# Jena tdbloader assembler

Tags: jena, tdbloader

How to load TDB storage with inference via tdbloader.bat (windows, Jena 2.7.3)?

I used this assembler file:

```
 @prefix tdb: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
 @prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
 @prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
 @prefix ja: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .
 @prefix tdb: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .

 [] ja:loadClass "com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDB" .
 tdb:DatasetTDB rdfs:subClassOf ja:RDFDataset .
 tdb:GraphTDB rdfs:subClassOf ja:Model .

  <#dataset> rdf:type ja:RDFDataset ;
          ja:defaultGraph <#infModel> .

   <#infModel>  a ja:InfModel ;
         ja:baseModel <#tdbGraph>; 
            ja:reasoner 
            [ ja:reasonerURL <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2003/OWLFBRuleReasoner> ].

    <#tdbGraph> rdf:type tdb:GraphTDB ;
                     tdb:location "DB";
 .
```

My command:

```
c:\apache-jena-2.7.3\bat>tdbloader --tdb=test.ttl C:\apache-jena-2.7.3\Lubm10\*
```

I got an exception:

```
   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.FBRuleInfGraph cannot be cast to com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.store.GraphTDB
```

What is wrong?
(removing semicolon after "DB" - does not help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. `tdbloader` is a tool for loading triples into a TDB store, prior to processing those triples via your app or SPARQL end-point. Separately, from your app code, you can construct a Jena model which uses the inference engine over a base model from a TDB graph. But I can't see why you are using an inference model at *load* time. If you look at the exception you are getting:

```
FBRuleInfGraph cannot be cast to com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.store.GraphTDB
```

it confirms that you can't use an inference graph at that stage of the process, and I'm not sure why you would. Unless, of course, you are trying to statically compute the inference closure over the base model and store that in TDB, saving the need for inference computation at runtime. However, if you *are* trying to do that, I don't believe that can currently be done via the Jena assembler. You'll have to write custom code to do that at the moment.

Bottom line: separate the concerns. Use a plain graph description for `tdbloader`, use the inference graph at run time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I am trying to achieve 'the need for inference computation at runtime'. I am doing it via Java code but on the small data (19 MB, Lubm generated data set for 2 Universities) the load time in TDB with OWL inference takes hours... 1) Read TDB dataset Lubm2 and make Model 2) Make InfModel with OWL reasoner and add Model from p.1 3) Create new empty TDB dataset and add InfModel from p.2 - takes hours and ended with access violation exception..